# ngclass expressions, is value in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using a ng-repeat and I want the ng-repeated element to have a conditional ng-class.

I want the conditional to be if the particular item is in an array then apply the condition.

I tried to use jQuery...and it didn't work. Here's what I have:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-class="($.inArray(user,selectedUser)?'ts-li-selected':''" ng-click="selectUser(user,$event,$index)">
```

and it's not working...is something like this possible, or will I have to do it more programmatically in the ng-click function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-class="{'ts-li-selected' : userSelected(user)}" ng-click="selectUser(user,$event,$index)">
```

then

```
$scope.userSelected =  function(user){
    return $.inArray(user, $scope.selectedUser) > -1;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wnnWu/)